# ROS Stage in Fuerte on 12.04 only supports 1 ranger or 1 sonar type how to do both

Tags: stageros, ubuntu, stage, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand that there is a ROS stage limitation of support where a robot is only allowed to have "rangers with 1 sensor only." As referenced [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/34661/prolbems-with-stage-pioneer-and-laserrangers-on/). As well as a rename of the Laser to rangers type, as referenced [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33973/stage-error-in-fuerte/).

Then how do I create a robot model to the specifications of my physical robot which will be compatible with ROS Stage 4.1.1? See [here](http://syrotek.felk.cvut.cz/about/robots) for breakdown of S1R. I have a mix of sonar, IR, and laser rangefinder. Currently, I would have to strip it down and only have one sensor on it, and I certainly don't want to do that.

What happened to the change in Stage that allowed multiple sensors as described in [here](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Simulating-multiple-laser-scanners-in-Stage-td2008197.html)?

The following world code is what I am working with:

```
include "S1R.inc"
include "hokuyo.inc"

S1R
(       
  # can refer to the robot by this name
  name "r0"
  pose [ 1.20 2.00 0 150 ]

  hokuyolaser(
    color "gray"
    pose [0.04 0.00 -0.11 0]
  )

  alwayson 1
  localization "gps"
  localization_origin [ 0 0 0 0 ]
  laser_return 0
)


window
(
  size [ 800 800 ] # in pixels
  scale 150.0
     # pixels per meteri
  center [ 1.7 1.8 ]
  rotate [ 0  0 ]


  view (       
    show_data 1              
    show_laser 1
    show_laser_strikes 1
    show_ranger 0
    show_mines 1
  )
)




###########################
# OBSTACLES
###########################


define obstacle model
(
  name "unknown"
  color  "orange"
  pose [0 0 0 0]
  size [0 0 0]
  gui_nose 0
  gui_grid 0
  gui_move 1
  gui_outline 0

  # insensible to collision and range sensors
  obstacle_return 1
  laser_return 1
  ranger_return 1  
)

obstacle(name "1" pose [1.71 0.02 0 90.0] size [0.04 3.34 0.25] color "brown")
obstacle(name "2" pose [1.71 3.7 0 90.0] size [0.04 3.34 0.25] color "brown")
obstacle(name "3" pose [0.02 1.86 0 0.0] size [0.04 3.72 0.25] color "brown")
obstacle(name "4" pose [3.4 1.86 0 0.0] size [0.04 3.72 0.25] color "brown")
obstacle(name "10" pose [2.26 0.5 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
#obstacle(name "11" pose [2.76 0.18 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
obstacle(name "22" pose [2.9 1.46 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
obstacle(name "26" pose [0.5 0.34 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "27" pose [0.18 0.66 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "28" pose [1.16 0.34 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "29" pose [1.48 0.34 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "30" pose [1.44 0.66 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "31" pose [2.1 0.66 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "32" pose [2.94 0.66 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "33" pose [0.98 0.48 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "34" pose [0.98 0.82 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "35" pose [0.66 0.8 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "36" pose [0.66 1.14 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "37" pose [0.34 1.12 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "38" pose [0.34 1.44 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "39" pose [1.14 1.62 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "40" pose [0.8 1.62 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "41" pose [0.48 1.62 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "42" pose [2.1 1.62 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "43" pose [2.44 1.62 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "44" pose [2.76 1.62 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "45" pose [2.74 0.98 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "46" pose [2.9 1.16 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "47" pose [2.26 1.16 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "48" pose [2.26 0.84 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "49" pose [1.62 1.46 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "50" pose [1.62 0.82 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "51" pose [2.76 0.5 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "52" pose [1.12 1.3 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.32 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "53" pose [1.3 1.14 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.36 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "54" pose [2.26 0.06 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.04 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "55" pose [0.34 1.85 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.42 0.25] color "gray49")
#obstacle(name "56" pose [0.34 2.2 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
#obstacle(name "57" pose [0.34 2.48 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
obstacle(name "58" pose [0.34 2.89 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.54 0.25] color "gray49")
#obstacle(name "59" pose [0.18 3.18 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
obstacle(name "60" pose [1.71 3.18 0 90.0] size [0.04 2.78 0.25] color "gray49")
#obstacle(name "61" pose [3.24 3.18 0 90.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
obstacle(name "62" pose [2.9 1.76 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.24 0.25] color "gray49")
#obstacle(name "63" pose [2.9 2.02 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.28 0.25] color "red")
obstacle(name "64" pose [2.9 2.52 0 0.0] size [0.04 0.72 0.25] color "gray49")
obstacle(name "76" pose [2.54 1.34 0 0.0] size [0.16 0.16 0.2] color "red")
obstacle(name "77" pose [0.28 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "78" pose [0.54 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "79" pose [0.8 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "80" pose [1.06 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "81" pose [1.32 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "82" pose [1.58 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "83" pose [1.84 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "84" pose [2.1 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "85" pose [2.36 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "86" pose [2.62 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "87" pose [2.88 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "88" pose [3.14 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.08 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "89" pose [0.05 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.02 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
obstacle(name "90" pose [3.37 3.59 0 0.0] size [0.02 0.18 0.13] color "brown")
```

Below is the S1R.inc file code, and the Hokuyo.inc used is the one that comes with the ROS Stage in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/stage/share/stage/worlds$

```
# Desc: definition file for SyRoTek S1R robot
# Author: Jan Chudoba
# Date: 2009-01-21
# Last update: 2009-01-22

define s1r_front_ir ranger (
        alwayson 1
        scount 2
        spose[0] [ 0.078 0.0335 -0.1 0.03] # front left
        spose[1] [ 0.078 -0.0335 0 0.03] # front right
        sview [0.05 0.35 2] # [min max fov]
        ssize [0.04 0.01]
        )

define s1r_base_ir ranger (
        alwayson 1
        scount 3
        spose[0] [ -0.020 0.063 90 0.07] # left
        spose[1] [ -0.020 -0.063 -90 0.07] # right
        spose[2] [ -0.078 0 180 ] # rear
        sview [0.05 0.35 2] # [min max fov]
        ssize [0.04 0.01]
        )

define s1r_base_sonar ranger (
        alwayson 1
        scount 3
        spose[0] [ -0.020 0.063 90 ] # left
        spose[1] [ -0.020 -0.063 -90 ] # right
        spose[2] [ -0.078 0 180 ] # rear
        sview [0.05 5.0 50] # [min max fov]
        ssize [0.04 0.01]
        )

define s1r_frontsensor_ir ranger (
        alwayson 1
        scount 3
        spose[0] [ 0.039 0.039 45 ] # left
        spose[1] [ 0.055 0 0 ] # center
        spose[2] [ 0.039 -0.039 -45 ] # rear
        sview [0.05 0.35 2] # [min max fov]
        ssize [0.04 0.01]
        )

define s1r_frontsensor_sonar ranger (
        alwayson 1
        scount 3
        spose[0] [ 0.039 0.039 45 ] # left
        spose[1] [ 0.055 0 0 ] # center
        spose[2] [ 0.039 -0.039 -45 ] # rear
        sview [0.05 5.0 50] # [min max fov]
        ssize [0.04 0.01]
        )

define S1R position 
(
#        localization "odom"
#   odom_error [0.0 0.01 0.0 0.01 0.0 0.01]

 color "blue"

 size [ 0.174 0.162 0.18]
 origin [0 0 0 0]
# gui_nose 1
 mass 2.0

# drive "diff"

 block(
     points 8
     point[7] [ 0.087  0.045 ]
     point[6] [ 0.087 -0.045 ]
     point[5] [ 0.050 -0.081 ]
     point[4] [-0.050 -0.081 ]
     point[3] [-0.087 -0.045 ]
     point[2] [-0.087  0.045 ]
     point[1] [-0.050  0.081 ]
     point[0] [ 0.050  0.081 ]
     z [0 0.06]
      )

 block( 
     points 8
     point[7] [ 0.075  0.030 ]
     point[6] [ 0.075 -0.030 ]
     point[5] [ 0.024 -0.059 ]
     point[4] [-0.062 -0.059 ]
     point[3] [-0.074 -0.050 ]
     point[2] [-0.074  0.050 ]
     point[1] [-0.062  0.059 ]
     point[0] [ 0.024  0.059 ]
     z [0.13 0.18]
     )

# block(    
#    points 6
#    point[5] [ 0.024 -0.059 ]
#    point[4] [-0.062 -0.059 ]
#    point[3] [-0.074 -0.050 ]
#    point[2] [-0.074  0.050 ]
#    point[1] [-0.062  0.059 ]
#    point[0] [ 0.024  0.059 ]
#    z [0.06 0.13]
#     )


    s1r_front_ir()
    s1r_base_ir()
    s1r_base_sonar()
    s1r_frontsensor_ir()
    s1r_frontsensor_sonar()
    )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38264/ros-stage-in-fuerte-on-12.04-only-supports-1-ranger-or-1-sonar-type-how-to-do-both/) by [paresh471](https://answers.ros.org/users/2797/paresh471/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like people have been [working on it for a long time](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/2561).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0